# PHP Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found

Tags: php, github, phpunit, phar, bigml

My Current PHP version: 7.1.28

My PHPUnit 7.5.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

PHPUnit installed with PHP Archive (PHAR)

➜ wget -O phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-7.phar

➜ chmod +x phpunit

➜ ./phpunit --version

but after installing PHPUnit with PHAR it isn't generate "src/autoload.php" but just only file phpunit

but if I run ./phpunit --version in terminal it's show PHPUnit 7.5.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

I download the zip in https://github.com/bigmlcom/bigml-php and extract it then I run it bigml-php-master/tests/test_00_regressions.php then I got an error message PHP Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found

can anybody help me please

Comment: I normally have `extends TestCase` and `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`, not sure if this is part of the stuff you've downloaded.

Comment: If I use 
extends TestCase;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

 got an error 

syntax error, unexpected 'extends' (T_EXTENDS), expecting end of file

Comment: If you show the line giving you the problem it should be easy to fix.

Comment: The class **PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase** is not in Phpunit 7 any longer (gone with Phpunit 6.5 IIRC). You can try to alias it to PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase but then you *might* run into additional problems. Check what @Nobu suggested, just to use a compatible version of Phpunit (the version he picked sounds reasonable to me). This should work out of the box.

Comment: And please don't forget to close your reported issue on Github: https://github.com/bigmlcom/bigml-php/issues/37 - This is not a problem with the project, it's just an incompatible Phpunit version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [bigml-php's README](https://github.com/bigmlcom/bigml-php/blob/master/README.rst#testing) doesn't specify which version of phpunit should be used, though it's probably 5.x while the test class extends old class name `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`.

You can still download [phpunit-5.7.27.phar](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-5.html). And it seems it's working:

```
./phpunit-5.7.27.phar test_00_regressions.php
```

Comment: Phpunit 5 should be compatible at least, sounds like a good suggestion to me.

Answer (score 0):

Latest method:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SampleTest extends TestCase
{

}
```